# How to Load Sqlite data in recycler view using kotlin with Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Iam working on a project where I have to load Sqlite data in recycler view and I'm using ROOM for this.Following is my adapter code :-

```
package com.example.demorecyclerview.adapter
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.room.Room
import com.example.demorecyclerview.MainActivity
import com.example.demorecyclerview.R
import com.example.demorecyclerview.database.contactDatabase
import com.example.demorecyclerview.entity.Contact
import java.lang.Exception
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference


class ContactAdapter() :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    /**
     * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using
     * (custom ViewHolder).
     */
         ContactAdapter.Companion.insertContactAsyncTask(this)

    private val name= arrayOf("abc","xyz","pqr")
    private val numbers= arrayOf("123","456","789")

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var nameTextView:TextView=view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName)
        var mobTextView:TextView=view.findViewById(R.id.textViewMobile)
//        val textView: TextView
//
//        init {
//            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
//            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView)
//        }
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.card_contacts, viewGroup, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the
        // contents of the view with that element
      viewHolder.nameTextView.text=name[position]
        viewHolder.mobTextView.text=numbers[position]
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun getItemCount() = name.size


    companion object {
        class insertContactAsyncTask internal constructor(context: ContactAdapter) : AsyncTask<Int, String, String?>() {
            var res:Long = 0;
            var context=context
            private val activityReference: WeakReference<ContactAdapter> = WeakReference(context)
            override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Int?): String? {
                try{
                    val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
                            context.,
                            contactDatabase::class.java, "quest_contacts"
                    ).build()
                    val contacts:List<Contact> = db.contactDao().getAllContacts()
                    Log.d("Results","$contacts")
                    return contacts.toString()
                }

                catch(e: Exception)
                {
                    Log.e("Exception","$e")
                }
                return ""
            }

//            override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
//               return result
//
//            }
        }

    }

}
```

As it is a normal class, so what should I pass as context in Room.databaseBuilder().When I'm calling
ContactAdapter.Companion.insertContactAsyncTask(this) it shows error "Expecting Member Declaration".Please help me resolving this.Thanks in advance....

Comment: Try not to call the database I/O operations in the adapter class, instead move the logic to a `repo`, create a livedata in the `viewModel` to store the data from the repo and use `bindingAdapter` to bind the data to recyclerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing `ContactAdapter.Companion.insertContactAsyncTask(this)` on a class level. On a class level, you can only declare the class's fields or methods, you can't execute code there. So you have to declare it, not create an object:

```
class ContactAdapter() :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private val getContacts = ContactAdapter.Companion.insertContactAsyncTask(this)
......
}
```

Then you have to execute your async task in places you want it to be executed from. Here for example it executes in a constructor:

```
constructor {
   getContacts.execute()
}
```

As for the context of `Room.databaseBuilder()`, it is not `ContactAdapter`. It is the class `Context` from `android.content` package. Given your code one way to pass it to `insertContactAsyncTask` is to add an argument of type `Context` to your `ContactAdapter`, then pass this argument to `insertContactAsyncTask`. Here is an example:

```
class ContactAdapter(val context: Context) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private val getContacts = ContactAdapter.Companion.insertContactAsyncTask(context)
    ......
    companion object {
    class insertContactAsyncTask internal constructor(context: Context) : AsyncTask<Int, String, String?>() {
        var res:Long = 0;
        var context=context
        private val activityReference: WeakReference<ContactAdapter> = WeakReference(context)
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Int?): String? {
            try{
                val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context,
                        contactDatabase::class.java, "quest_contacts"
                ).build()
                val contacts:List<Contact> = db.contactDao().getAllContacts()
                Log.d("Results","$contacts")
                return contacts.toString()
            }

            catch(e: Exception)
            {
                Log.e("Exception","$e")
            }
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```